# Scheduled php script is not working

Tags: php, windows, scheduled-tasks, sftp

I wanted to schedule an execution of a script in php every 10 min.

This PHP script does

1. Connect to a FTP server and download some XML files with ftp_get
2. Move all file downloaded in an archive folder in that FTP server(close connection)
   THEN
3. In local Transform that xml in txt (use of fopen, fwrite, fclose) put XML in a local archive folder
4. Connect to an SFTP server and send (with sftp put function) the txt renamed

I included ('Net/SFTP.php'); a library to connect to SFTP.

I used as server XAMPP, i stored my php script in a folder under htdocs and also a cmd batch file.
I create a schedule with windows scheduler with this code

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f C:\xampp\htdocs\testSftp\catchXML_FTP_V4.php
```

Problem is that if i execute manually with broswer all is good, but when the script is executed with the scheduler that call batch file (cmd) it do just the 1 and 2 point of the script, only two times it did well.

How is this caused and how can I fix it?

Comment: Do you capture the script output? What errors, if any does it produce?

Comment: Well, debug the code! Seriously, do you think anyone could guess what the issue is with code you haven't show? Do you think anyone will guess the errors you haven't provided either?

Comment: -.-' No error, i wrote it, now for example i run manually bat file and all is good

Comment: That does not mean there's no error when you run the script from the scheduler. Put your command to a batch file, with redirect like `C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f C:\xampp\htdocs\testSftp\catchXML_FTP_V4.php > c:\writablepath\ftp.log`. And run the batch file from the scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a relative path to the included files, make sure that the starting directory of the scheduled task is the script directory.

Because, by default it will be the `php.exe` directory `C:\xampp\php`, where the `Net/SFTP.php` is not a valid path.

Comment: i put the bat file in the same folder of php script and i copied all the libssh php lib in the same folder. I need to put included (C:\xampp\php\Net\SFTP.php') ???

Comment: I retry now with 10 xml file, if i manually click bat script all is done! With window scheduler only do first and second point. How? The scheduler just execute automatically the same bat script!! :(((( Which are the differences??